# C# EF6 save datetimeoffset

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have simpleobject

```
class SimpleObject
{
   public int id { get; set;}
   public System.DateTimeOffset timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

And method in Controler

```
private dbEntities db = new dbEntities();
public object SaveSO()
    {
        SimpleObject so = new SimpleObject();
        DateTimeOffset ts = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        try
        {
            so.timestamp = ts;
            db.SimpleObject.Add(so);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View("index");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            Debug.Write (ts + " ---> " + ex);
            return View("index");
        }
    }
```

Controler save a object in DB but time is null. why?

Comment: It is crazy but I removed ADO.NET and added it back again and it worked.

Maybe this will help someone not to waste time on this.